# TFS Update 1 vNext Build: One "Associated Change" From Last Build Appears in Next Build

Tags: tfs, build, azure-pipelines

I've been tasked with creating two new vNext build scripts which we will use as templates for future builds. One is being created on TFS Update 1 and the other is on TFS Update 3.

The TFS Update 1 build script (and apparently any build scripts on this installation) have an issue where the last "Associated Change" from a build reappears as an associated change on the next build. This occurs regardless of the number of changes and the number of builds (successful or failed) in between.

For example, see the following scenario (notice how the last associated change in one build is always the first associated change in the next build).

Build 1 (Successful, 3 checkins occurred)

--Associate Changes

----4040

----4052

----4059

Build 2 (Successful, 2 checkins occured)

--Associated Changes

----4059

----4062

----4066

Build 3 (Successful, 0 checkins occurred)

--Associated Changes

----4066

Build 4 (Failed, 1 checkin occurred)

--Associated Changes

----4066

----4072

This situation DOES NOT occur on TFS Update 3. I haven't found any documentation stating that it's a bug in Update 1 that was resolved in Update 2 or Update 3, but have not ruled that out.

Has anybody seen this behavior before and know the cause? I need to either be able to resolve the issue or identify it as within the product itself.

Update 2 Release Notes:
https://www.visualstudio.com/news/releasenotes/tfs2015-update2-vs

Update 3 Release Notes:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2015-update3-vs

Comment: I just noticed that my question was downvoted. I'm new to the system here, so any advice on how to improve it would be appreciated. Unfortunately, as this is a case of not being able to find documentation on the matter, supplying sources isn't feasible unless it's beneficial to provide links to the Update 2 and Update 3 release notes for verification that such a change is not mentioned in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested in TFS 2015 (no update) and TFS 2015.3, and could reproduce your scenario.

In TFS 2015, each build will associate a changeset in last build, but in TFS 2015.3, only failed changeset will be associated in the next build.

This issue is from product itself, and has been fixed in the TFS 2015.3.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to recreate and confirm!